# bootstrap modal is not working,where to paste this code in file?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below mentioned code is not working in my project, modal is not displaying in browser.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">No of items purchased</button>
         <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
           <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
             <div class="modal-content"><br>
                <h4>hi</h4>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: best include that "below mentioned code"

Comment: Look [Here](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/bootstrap/modal.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is perfect please check whether you have added bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css, also check these files have proper link and loaded before you call bootstrap modal. few things you should keep in mind even i struggled with this problem.

1: Check proper links have been provided to load bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css

2: Load Jquery.js before loading bootstrap.js and
    bootstrap.css.

3: Check the spelling of src, if you are begainer 
        sometimes what happens is you write scr instead of src.

4: Check the bootstrap version you are using.

Comment: i just did mistake no.3 :-)